# POST "base64 image string" not working in iOS 11

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking-3

Previously I'm saving "base64imagestring" on server using AFNetworking POST method and it's working fine but now from last couple of days i am facing some issues. I didn't change any thing in the request code but i am not able to upload base64imagestring on server.

```
Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set., NSUnderlyingError=0x281f25170 {Error Domain= example.com Code=-1011 "Request failed: unacceptable (406)" UserInfo=<NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x2811e4be0> { URL: http://example.com/Api/image_save.php } { Status Code: 406, Headers {
    Connection =     (
        "Keep-Alive"
    );
    "Content-Length" =     (
        226
    );
    "Content-Type" =     (
        "text/html; charset=iso-8859-1"
    );
    Date =     (
        "Wed, 29 May 2019 07:11:52 GMT"
    );
    "Keep-Alive" =     (
        "timeout=5, max=75"
    );
    Server =     (
        Apache
    );
} }}}}
```

Comment: That's from the response, and it's not a JSON. There have been a change on the server? It be good to retrieve the content which is not JSON, but seems to be html.

Comment: if your content was a base64 image string, then the Content-Length would have certainly been larger than 226 bytes, so, I suggest that something threw off the Content-Length header.  I'm also not sure about your Content-Type of text/html, maybe text/plain or image/jpg would be necessary.  Typically in URLs it is data:image/jpg; base64